# Norm of covariance between scalar and vector

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, statistics, random-variables, covariance

I would like to show that if $Y\in\Re$ is a random real vector such that $\|Y\|≤ \bar Y$ and $X \in \mathcal H$ where $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space (whose field is $\Re$), then 
$$
\|\operatorname{Cov} (Y,X)\| = \|E(YX^*)\| ≤ \bar Y \|X\|_∞.
$$
The first idea is the following: if $X∈ \Re^p$, then I think that
$$
\|\operatorname{Cov} (Y,X)\| = \|E(YX^T)\| ≤ \sqrt{\operatorname{Var} (Y)}\max_{i=1,\ldots,p}\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}  (X_i)}
$$
which would yield the first equation based on the fact that if $|Z|≤\nu$, then $\operatorname{Var} (Z) ≤ ν^2$.

The second idea (which yields the desired inequality in the real case when $X_i$ are independent one to each other) is to consider the fact that $X$ has limited total information upon $Y$.